# How do I configure url for static files and media in development?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm developing an application in which I need to put images on the screen. I configured the "settings" file as explained in the django tutorial.
But for some reason the images are not found.

settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_ROOT,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('licitacao.urls')),
]   + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

exemple.html

```
<img class="card-img-top figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="{% static "media/800x600.png" %}" alt="Card image cap">
```

If I change the url static by media, the image appears, however, static files like css and js stop working. How do I run the media and static together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you handle saving your images?
Do you use `FileField` or `ImageField` in your model?

Say you have a a model like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    condo = models.ForeignKey(Condo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    **image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")**
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then in your template you shouldn't be using `static` or `media`, but:

`<img src="{{ object.image.url }}">`

This will generate the correct url to your image.

Also, don't forget to add MEDIA_URL to routes.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I forgot to add the route in the URL. Thank you for your help. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do not merge `static` and `media` in same path, keep them different. Something like this.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Then try it. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

As well as Piyush's answer, you must not have STATIC_ROOT as one of STATICFILES_DIRS. They're separate settings for a reason; keep them separate.